# databaseSnapshot null reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullreferenceexception

I am using dataSnapshot to get a value from my Firebase Database, but I keep getting a null reference error. The path to my firebase is correct and I have Datasnapshot defined, so I am not too sure why this error is coming up.

Here is the snippit that is giving me issues

```
    User user = new User();
    String username;
    username = (String) datasnapshot.child("Users").child(uid).child("userName").getValue();
    user.setusername(username);
    navuserName.setText(username);
```

and this is the error that it is giving me.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I have `Datasnapshot dataSnapshot;` defined in the class but the error is being thrown. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `dataSnapshot` is not initialized. It's value is `null`. You need to initialize the variable before you can use it's methods.